# How to add student attendance in Open edX.

Tags: python, edx, openedx

I am a new developer for Open edX. I want to add student attendance, whoever has attained the course. I did google but not get any solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "student attendance"? Basically what you want to do?

Comment: Thankyou @IsankaWijerathne for your response, Actually I am Moodle developer, recently I have moved to Open edX. In Moodle, i have added [attendance](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_attendance)  plugin for  Student attendance, Same like, I want to add in edX.

Comment: There is no such a thing in Open edX. Can explain why do you need such a thing?  sometimes we may be able to suggest a workaround. 
And please do some research on classical LMS vs MOOC platforms.

Comment: Hey @IsankaWijerathne, Suppose that I will give the training on any particular course and enroll 100 of student that will attempt the training but any reason 10 students out of 100 students not attempt the training. How will you know which 10 students did not attempt the training?

Comment: If your training course contains graded questions/assignments then at the end of the course you can have a grade report and see who has completed the course. Other than that if you have "Open edX Insights" you can see learner engagements and active learners.

Comment: Hey @IsankaWijerathne, can we achieve such kind of thing? there instructor(trainer) or teacher will manually mark to peoples(Student) that have attempted the training.

Comment: This thread is getting longer and going out of the main question. Do we have any other way to communicate? In that way, I think I might be able to help more.

Comment: Sorry @IsankaWijerathne, I have searched but did not find, how to communicate with you.

Comment: Hey, @IsankaWijerathne Can we chat with Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you would like to enroll users by sending the right link related to the course?  If so all you have to do is :

- login as the LMS admin. ( staff@example.com  by default )
- click on the course you want to get users enrolled in
- click on  *instructor* bar menu  then on *membership*
- on *Batch Enrollment*. you can add all emails you want to get them enrolled in your course.

If you don't know what is you current superuser name you can create one like this:

`$ sudo su edxapp -s /bin/bash` 
  `$  cd`
   `$ /edx/bin/python.edxapp /edx/bin/manage.edxapp lms manage_user staff staff@example.com --staff --superuser --settings=aws`

*Notes: you can change the staff and staff@example.com  by your own superuser name and email.*

Then you can change the superuser password as follows:

`$ cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/`
`$ /edx/bin/python.edxapp ./manage.py lms --settings aws changepassword staff`

Comment: I think it's not about enrolling, It's about attendance.

Comment: Hey, @SAM.Am thankyou for your response. I am telling about attendance. Who has the completed any particular course training and knowing how many peoples(Student) complete the training.